# How to change images using jQuery and setTimeout?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to change an image with setTimeout in jQuery. I tried this but didn't get the answer. I mean which the images doesn't change . please help...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li") .each(function(){
        thisdisplay = $(this).css("display");
        if (thisdisplay == 'block') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).next().fadeIn().css("display", "block");
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

and html:

```
   <ul>
     <li id="li1" class="showed"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
     <li id="li2"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
     <li id="li3"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
     <li id="li4"><img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   </ul>
```

and css:

```
ul li {display:none;}
.showed {display:block;}
```

Comment: You need to clearly explain **what** isn't working. Show your HTML.

Comment: Ok, I've retracted my close-vote. I'd still expect you to explain *what* isn't working with your current code, and to explain what you've done to isolate the problem though. *I tried this but didn't get the answer* is not specific enough.

Comment: The Images doesn't change!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/AMvpp/1/) is a solution to your problem.
All jQuery code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count=0
        setInterval(function() {
            $('li img').hide()
            if(count===4){count=0}
               count++
               $('#li'+count).find('img').show()

            }, 500);

})
</script>
```